# How to configure kafka transaction manager with spring transaction in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka in the spring boot application. I want to perform operations in one transaction like given below.

```
listen(){
 produce()
 saveInDb()
}
```

and

```
operation(){
 saveInDB()
 produce()
}
```

I have enabled Kafka transactions using the below configurations

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092
    producer:
      transaction-id-prefix: tx-
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
      isolation-level: read_committed
```

and using this configuration

```
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Object> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix("tx-");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager() {
        KafkaTransactionManager manager = new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory());
        return manager;
    }
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
```

But I am getting an error when tried with spring @Transactional annotation

```
@Transactional
operation(){
 saveInDB()
 produce()
}
```

```
No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
```

I followed the spring docs here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#using-kafkatransactionmanager

What am I missing in the configuration?

Comment: Have you tried using `@Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")`?

Comment: Yes, but getting the same error

Comment: what about using a the outbox pattern instead of dealing two transaction managers
https://mirakl.tech/sending-kafka-message-in-a-transactional-way-34d6d19bb7b2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was missing defining transactionManager bean in configuration.
Spring was not able to find it  because `KafkaTransactionManager` extends `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` and `JpaTransactionManager` also extends the same class.

Defining this bean as the primary bean fixed the issue.

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
```

Kafka transactions get chained with it and `KafkaTemplate` will synchronize a transaction with transaction manager.

Reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: Were you able to make this work? Once I configure this the app starts up fine but my spring boot application has trouble with the "InitProducerId" as it keeps timing out.  `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId`

Comment: @KartheekMannepalli I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @DhirenSolanki - In my case the issue was with the kafka cluster. I only had one broker running but the minimum needed for transactions were 2. Setting these values resolved the issue for me. `transaction.state.log.min.isr=1` and `transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1`. Check your kafka logs if you still see issues.

Comment: I'm also trying to make kafka transactions work with database transactions. I reproduced everything, including enabling transactions, making database transaction manager primary and changing my kafka cluster properties, but still it doesnt work: upon unsuccessful database update, the kafka messages are delivered (commited).

Comment: @KartheekMannepalli I am hitting the same error, but setting both parameters to 1 does not help. Could you explain a bit more why setting them both to 1 was your solution, when you said the minimum number of brokers is 2? Thanks.

Comment: @YvesCalaci same behaviour here. Were you ever able to fix this?